# About the orthogonality of columns in Zadoff-Chu matrix

Tags: frequency-spectrum, spread-spectrum, orthogonal-signals, code-generator

As we know that Zadoff-Chu matrix is similar to Walsh-Hadamard matrix where every columns in those matrices is orthogonal with the any other column.

For Walsh-Hadmard matrix, the orthogonality is clear and can be demonstrated easily. But regarding the Zadoff-Chu matrix, I don't see that orthogonality is right as shown below:

```
a = (sqrt(2) + 1j*sqrt(2))/2;
W = [a 1 a -1; -1 a 1 a ; a -1 a 1; 1 a -1 a];  %%Zadoff-Chu matrix 

C1 = W(:,1);     %% Take the first column

orth_results = []; 
for j = 1 : size(W,2)
    results = (abs(sum(W(:,j).*C1)).^2);  %Project the first column to every column in matrix W
    orth_results = [orth_results results];
end
```

Following the condition of orthogonality between columns, `orth_results` should be equals to 0 except in the fist value, but what I get is `orth_results = [8.0000         0    8.0000      0];`

What's the problem of that? Is there any issue in the matrix itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex matrices, the concept of orthogonality is replaced by [unitarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix). If $^H$ denotes the  conjugate transpose of a matrix, we should check that $W$ is a unitary matrix (up to a scaling factor) via equations:

$$W^*  W = WW^*  =\lambda I$$

with $\lambda\neq 0$, which you can test positively with:

```
W'*W
W*W'
```

What is missing in your loop, and especially in the **complex scalar product**, is the conjugation on one of the complex vectors. This is explained for instance in [Wikipedia/Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) for [Complex vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Complex_vectors).

You could for instance replace `C1` by `conj(C1)`.

Comment: Yes, that's condition is verified, it's OK. but Why when can't I proof the orthogonality of each columns by projecting it on the other columns?

Comment: The conjugation is missing in the scalar product. Try `conj(C1)` instead of `C1`. Conjugation is implicit in the matrix transpose operator

Comment: Thank you so much .. I got it.